# I get this syntax error in Verilog: unexpected <=

Tags: syntax, verilog

```
module mux ( in1 , in2 , sel , out1 );
  input wire [31:0] in1 , in2;
  output reg [31:0] out;
  input wire sel;

  case (sel)
    0 : begin out1 <= in1 ; end 
    default : begin out1 <= in2 ; end
  endcase 

endmodule
```

the error is:

> ** Error: (vlog-13069) C:/Modeltech_pe_edu_10.4a/examples/mux.v(9): near "<=": syntax error, unexpected <=.
>
> ** Error: C:/Modeltech_pe_edu_10.4a/examples/mux.v(9): (vlog-13205) Syntax error found in the scope following 'out1'. Is there a missing '::'?

Answer (score 1):

Two errors:

1. `out` should be `out1`
2. The `case` statement must be inside an `always` block

Also, for combinational logic, you should use blocking assignments (`=`).

```
module mux ( in1 , in2 , sel , out1 );

input wire [31:0] in1 , in2;

output reg [31:0] out1;

input wire sel;

always @(*) begin
    case (sel)
        0 : begin out1 = in1 ; end
        default : begin out1 = in2 ; end
    endcase
end

endmodule
```